# Page still showing advance custom fields value even if I changed the template in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, templates, advanced-custom-fields

Hey everyone I came across this strange behavior. Actually I assigned Advance Custom Field to default template and that template was used in particular page so I entered the values in advance custom fields and displayed them in appropriate places in page.php.

But I now created a new template inner-template.php and assigned it to that page so now no ACF is showing in that page in edit mode but it is still displaying the ACF values when I call ACFs in inner-template.php.

Why this is occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's known behaviour of ACF. It occurs, because ACF doesn't delete field's values, when you change some conditions (for example, change the template for the page). You should do it manually before changing template or you can clear this fields directly from `wp_postmeta` table.